# uninitialized constant ActiveRecord Model in rake script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm using rails 2.3.2 with ruby 1.8.7. I got some problems with my rake scripts. It seems it cannot load any activerecord model with production environment at all. It's so weird that is working with development environment. Here is my rake script:

```
task :indexing, :domain_name, :needs => :environment do |t, args|
   ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(RAILS_ENV)

   unless args.domain_name.blank?
      portals = [Portal.find_by_domain_name(args.domain_name)]
   else
      portals = Portal.actives
   end
end
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the error you get from that?

Comment: uninitialized constant Portal

Comment: Does it work if you remove temporarily `, :domain_name, :needs` part?

Comment: It works, so what should I do? How to add parameter and load rails env at the same time?

Comment: I tried quickly with Rails 2.3.2 and it seems to work? What is your rake version?

Comment: Do you run your rake task like this: `rake indexing RAILS_ENV=production`?

Comment: Actually, it has a namespace. I ran with `rake solr:indexing RAILS_ENV=production` with rake version 0.8.7

Comment: I think your problem is somewhere else than in the rake task. Try similar task with new app with just one model. That worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(RAILS_ENV)`.

This part loads your environment already: `=> :environment`

Comment: Are your production db settings correct and is the db schema up to date? Try to access `Portal` with `script/console production`.

Comment: script/console production, it works as usual except in rake script. It's so weird.